# How to compile .deb file from package archives?

Tags: 12.10, deb, launchpad, archive

How do I make .deb package file from these archives? http://ppa.launchpad.net/unit3/bfgminer/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/

Comment: `checkinstall`? mybe?

Comment: Which files I need to use with checkinstall? Maybe source/sources.bz2?

Comment: follow the instructions on how to install your source files then when you encounter `sudo make install`, change it to `sudo checkinstall -D` which after the installation, you will see a .deb package of the installed application.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `apt-build` command. In short:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-build
sudo apt-build update
sudo apt-build build-source <package>
```

That assumes that you have added the repo you want to build in your `sources.list`.

Good luck!

Comment: I need to use armhf architecture, so I need to use binary-armhf, debian-installer/binary-armhf or source folder? And when I will use build-source I need to specify folder name in <package>? Can you give me example? Sorry, I am new to ubuntu.

Comment: I get an error:
dpkg: error processing apt-build (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
apt-build
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Sorry for my late response. So you need to cross compile for armhf. Check out the link i posted in [this](https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/DevPlatform/CrossCompile/CrossbuildingQuickStart) answer, should be thing you need.